# Calculation Returns Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that checks the values of the child images heights, then sets the parents height to the value of the smallest image's height, then adds `overflow: hidden` to avoid overflow.

I execute the function from the `document.ready` event, however I am getting odd results. I will get HTMLobjectHeight, 0, undefined, or the correct value on a pageload. Why is this varying? is it firing before the images are loaded?

```
function setContainHeight() 
{
    var container = $('.com-background');
    var imgs = $('.com-background img');
    var smallestImg = imgs[0];
    $(imgs).each(function() 
    {
        if ($(this).height() < $(smallestImg).height() )
            smallestImg = $(this).height();

    });

    container.height(smallestImg);
    container.css("overflow", "hidden");
};
```

One other issue I am having is, when I add this function to the `window.resize` event it also fires on pageload, and gives an undefined result.

HTML

```
<div class="com-background" style="height: 434px; overflow: hidden;">
    <h1 class="community_title">Sun Lakes</h1>
    <img width="250" height="167" src="http://192.168.33.10.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Ocotillo-lake-e1404789921289.jpg" class="wp-post-image" alt="Ocotillo - lake" style="display: block; z-index: 1;">
    <img width="250" height="188" src="http://192.168.33.10.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Resort-e1404789892490.jpg" class="attachment-post-secondary-image-thumbnail active" alt="Resort" style="z-index: 3; opacity: 0.988634061784097;">
    <img width="837" height="378" src="http://192.168.33.10.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/homestead-error.png" class="attachment-post-tert-image-thumbnail" alt="homestead-error" style="z-index: 2;">  <div class="numeric_search">
</div>
```

SASS/CSS

```
.com-background 
{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    img 
    {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: inherit;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your relevant HTML and CSS too.

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML, not the PHP, unless you think the PHP is relevant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the images have been loaded, start with a `$(window).load` event listener

I'd also use `Math.min` to get the lowest image height

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(event) {

  // find container
  var container = $(".com-background");

  // get image heights in an array
  var heights = container.find("img").map(function(idx, elem) {
    return $(elem).height();
  }).get();

  // get the minimum height
  var minimum = Math.min.apply(null, heights);

  // set container height and overflow property
  container.height(minimum).css({overflow: "hidden"});
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined

Comment: nice, works great. Now I will extract it to a function so I can use for resize event as well. Unless you think there is a better way to change the container size on `window.resize`?

Comment: @Chris, I do encourage you to decompose the event listener, but you can simply use `$(window).on("load resize", fn);` to attach to both events. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get all of height of images , you need to be sure that all images was downloaded and ready to used ... To be sure, you need use $(window).load() instead of $(document).read like that:

```
$(window).load( function() {
  setContainHeight();
  $(window).resize( setContainHeight );
});
```